# How to convert this sql to EF LINQ

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, linq

how to convert sql to linq, entity?

```
select Productdeltail.*,tv.sale,tv.idsale,tv.dateTo,tv.datefrom 
from Productdeltail
left join 
    (select SaleDetail.idProduct, SaleDetail.idSize, SaleDetail.sale,Sale.idsale,dateTo,datefrom from SaleDetail
    join Sale on SaleDetail.idsale = Sale.idsale 
    where (GETDATE() >= Sale.dateTo and GETDATE() <= Sale.datefrom ) ) tv on Productdeltail.idProduct= tv.idProduct and Productdeltail.idSize= tv.idSize
```

Comment: You don't. EF is an ORM, just like NHibernate. You create entities with relations and map them to tables. After that, the ORM generates the actual SQL queries each time you try to load entities and their relations. It looks like you have `Sale`, `SaleDetail` and `Product`entities in your applications.

Comment: It's easier to use `Database.SqlQuery`

Comment: If you configure the entities and mappings, all you need to do is write something like `from sale in dbContext.Sales from detail in sale.Details where sale.DateTo>=DateTime.Now and sale.DateFrom >=DateTime.Now select new { Details=detail.ProductDetail, detail.Sale,detail.idSale,sale.DateFrom,Sale.DateTo}`. Or reverse the query `from detail in context.SalesDetails let sale =detail.Sales where sale.DateTo <=DateTime.Now and sale.DateFrom >=DateTime.Now select detail`. The resulting `SalesDetail` objects will also pull the related `ProductDetail`, `Sale` objects

Comment: In fluent form this could look like `dbContext.SalesDetail.Where(detail=>detail.Sale.DateFrom<=DateTime.Now ....).Select(..)`

Comment: Perhaps my [SQL to LINQ Recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245160/sql-to-linq-with-multiple-join-count-and-left-join/49245786#49245786) will help you.